# Modifying recovery partition

Tags: partitioning, file-association, system-recovery, recovery-partition

In these days, laptops are being sold with a recovery partition by default (so you don't need any CD's and drivers) - just <kbd>F9</kbd> at Bootup and restore.

I have an Asus G73JH.

The **recovery partition** contains Win7 but has tons of ASUS trashy SW/tools on it, which I wanna get rid of.  Is there any possibility how to remove just the Asus SW from the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I can find searching, HP has improved their recovery manager, you can reinstall the OS without the added software, not sure if Asus allows you to do this or not.

As an alternative back up your non miscrosoft drivers using [DoubleDriver](http://www.boozet.org/dd.htm) to an external drive.

Then use one of these [ISO files](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/04/28/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/) to create a W7 install disc. Be sure to pick the same version and bit level as came with your PC.

Install and then use your OEM key found on the COA sticker to get it installed and activated. Record this OEM key somewhere safe, as the COA sticker will become unreadable at some point.

Then install and use DD to restore your drivers.

Comment: In my experience with Acers, the Windows key on the sticker doesn't match the installed key in a lot of cases. Good tip!

Comment: Installed key from manufacturer is a Volume Licence Key (VLK), the one on the COA sticker is a single user OEM key which should work with OEM W7 install disc I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is gonna work on Asus, because i don't know if ASUS have a special partition and etc... but works on **SAMSUNG** and probably it'll work fine on ASUS
First, press the **Start Button** and **R** and type **diskpart**
After this, type **list disk**
And then, type **select Disk X** the **X** you can replace with your disk Number
And after this, type **list volume** and select the **RECOVERY VOLUME** using **select volume X** the **X** you can replace with the recovery volume number, in SAMSUNG Laptops, the volume is called **SAMSUNG_REC**
After you select it, you type **Assign Letter=X** the **x** is the letter than you want, **DON'T** put C or any letter in use

Comment: First, this question has already been answered. Second, actually modifying the recovery partition is NOT the way to remove extraneous software. The recovery images are signed and will not run if they have been modified. The accepted answer is the correct way to get a clean install if the built-in recovery options do not include this ability. Please avoid posting unhelpful information as answers.